# Deployment error: Bad target server ID tomcat70:home

Tags: apache, tomcat, netbeans, tomcat6, netbeans-7

i am started using netbeans7.4 , when iam trying to run a web application, iam getting below error.. i searched in google, BUT didnt understood how to rectify it.. So, please someone suggest me on how to resolve below issue..

**Here is error:**

```
Deployment error: Bad target server ID tomcat70:home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
See the server log for details.
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:273)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.performDeploy(ExecutionChecker.java:205)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.executionResult(ExecutionChecker.java:123)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.java:235)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad target server ID tomcat70:home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.projects.DeploymentTarget.getServer(DeploymentTarget.java:270)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:192)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Can Anyone tell please?

Comment: can anyone please reply? does my query is tough?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem when I was messing with the server setup. I had removed and re-added the server configuration. Right click on the project, go to properties and make sure a server is selected under the "Run" configuration.